# How to use Structured Streaming to copy parquet files from HDFS to MS SQL Server?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to copy parquet files in HDFS to MS Sql Server using Spark Streaming. 
I am using JDBC driver for MS SQL Server. 
My code is:

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().master("yarn").appName("StreamAFile").getOrCreate();
val userSchema = new StructType().add("mandt","string").add("lifnr","string").add("land1","string").add("name1","string").add("name2","string");
val myDF = spark.readStream.format("parquet").schema(userSchema).load("/parquetfilepath/*");
val query = myDF.writeStream.format("jdbc").option("driver","net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable","mytable").option("user","username").option("password","password").option("checkpointLocation","/homedirectory/").start("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://SQLServer1:1433;DatabaseName=MyDB");
```

I am getting error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source jdbc does not support streamed writing
```

Please provide fix if anyone worked on this before.

Answer (score 1):

spark of structured streaming provide a `foreach()` function, you can use it to define a `JDBCSink()` by yourself. [This link](https://github.com/cynthia1wang/jdbcsink/blob/master/src/main/scala/DNSstat.scala) is a good demonstration for using mysql in structured streaming.
https://github.com/cynthia1wang/jdbcsink/blob/master/src/main/scala/DNSstat.scala

```
class JDBCSink() extends ForeachWriter[Row] {
    val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    var connection:Connection = _
    var statement:Statement = _

    def open(partitionId: Long,version: Long): Boolean = {
        Class.forName(driver)
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.88.1.102:3306/aptwebservice", "root", "mysqladmin")
        statement = connection.createStatement
        true
    }
    def process(value: Row): Unit = {
        statement.executeUpdate("replace into DNSStat(ip,domain,time,count) values(" 
                                + "'" + value.getString(0) + "'" + ","//ip
                                + "'" + value.getString(1) + "'" + ","//domain
                                + "'" + value.getTimestamp(2) + "'" + "," //time
                                + value.getLong(3) //count
                                + ")") 
}
    def close(errorOrNull: Throwable): Unit = {
        connection.close
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says:

> Data source jdbc does not support streamed writing

it's not possible in Structured Streaming. You may get better results using the older Spark Streaming API (but I would not recommend going this way because it's getting more and more obsolete).

Why do you even use Structured Streaming for this? Why don't you write a batch Spark application, i.e. `spark.read` and `spark.write`? That should work and with cron you could have regular executions.

p.s. I don't think I'd use Spark for such job (pun intended). I think Oozie or similar could be a better fit for this use case. There's no distributed processing that would let Spark shine I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Jacek. The reason I was using structured streaming is to have a real time copying data to SQL Server. I anticipate batch Spark application is going to execute sequentially, rather than parallel.

Comment: The same applies to Structured Streaming (it's still batch-oriented). That's why I was so "keen" on proposing some alternatives. _No magic_